# How to trigger manually container refresh

Tags: azure, for-loop, web-applications, containers

I am using WebApp for Container in Azure, currently I build my own containers in Jenkins and push it to my own private registry.

My Own private registry is very basic and doesn't have functionality for WebHook, so I would like to add in my Jenkins workflow to trigger the container refresh.

I have followed these steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-ci-cd and I got the URL but when I try to curl to it I got:

*401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.* if I do a GET request like:

curl https://$user:password@mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/docker/hook

and

*HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.* if I do a POST request

curl -X POST curl https://$user:password@mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/docker/hook

How I should do the request with Curl to trigger this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

Solution:

Simple as:

curl -X POST 'curl https://$user:password@mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/docker/hook' -H '' -d ''

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to escape the dollar sign at the beginning of the username.

So, for example:

```
curl https://\$user:password@mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/docker/hook'
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all

```
curl -X POST curl https://$user:password@mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/docker/hook
```

The first error here is on `$user`. When you start a word with `$` your terminal will think that it's an environment variable. So for your terminal considerer as a string, you have to put a `\` before the `$`.

Now we have this

```
curl -X POST curl https://\$user:password@mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/docker/hook
```

The second error is because there are some special characters in this url. So you have to put between quotes.

Now, we have this

```
curl -X POST curl "https://\$user:password@mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/docker/hook"
```

Finishing we have to add the parameters `-H` and `-d` at the end of the command.

Now the command

```
curl -X POST curl "https://\$user:password@mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/docker/hook" -d -H
```

should work.

Comment: This worked for me. Just to note that the webhook url nowadays looks like: https://$user:password@mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/registry/webhook