# Azure App Service Continuous Deployment Webhook doesn't work

Tags: azure, docker, webhooks, continuous-deployment, azure-web-app-service

(I already [asked in the Microsoft Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/23652497-4391-42d9-9b37-003a7baa8930/app-service-private-registry-webhook-doesnt-work?forum=AzureContainerServices) but didn't get an answer.)

I have an App Service using a private registry with Continuous Deployment enabled. The app is running totally fine but the Webhook URL for the Continuous Deployment doesn't work.

Here's the output of an HTTP GET request to the webhook:

```sh
$ curl https://\$MySiteName:SomeLongPassword@mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/docker/hook
"No route registered for '/docker/hook'"
```

Someone in the Microsoft Forum told me to try a POST request, so here's the output of that:

```sh
$ curl -X POST https://\$MySiteName:SomeLongPassword@mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/docker/hook
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Length Required</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Length Required</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

I haven't found anywhere in the Microsoft Azure docs how to use the webhook.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger manually container refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46766903/how-to-trigger-manually-container-refresh)

Comment: @juan Looks like it's the same solution I ended up with, so technically it does answer my question, I just wish I had found that question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After more searching, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46769983/1652265).

The answer suggests to do the following:

```sh
curl https://\$MySiteName:SomeLongPassword@mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/docker/hook -H "" -d ""
```

No idea why this works and I wish there was something in the Azure docs.

Comment: what that does is invoking (with an http request) a webhook that tells Azure that "something" has happened (e.g: a new image is ready) so that Azure can pull it and run another container

Comment: This works because using the curl flag `-d` (`-data`) implies HTTP method `POST`, which is the only method allowed for this webhook URL

Answer (score 0):

Selected answer didn't work for me in 2024. But such POST request did the thing:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://***'
```

`--request` defines 'POST' method.

`--location` follows redirect if 3XX HTTP status and "location" header are returned in response.